# Get process state

Tags: java, processbuilder

How can I get the state of a process or the context of a process, or the heap value of a process during execution?

I am creating processes using `ProcessBuilder`, any other sugestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think what "the heap value" is? You might look at jconsole or jvisualvm, though.

Comment: Thanks #Ingo, but i don't think so that jconsole will help me, I wants to get the state of a process, and later use that state to resume the process, from where it stops. It's part of my university project.

Comment: According to the Java SE docu, the only things you can do with a process is to kill it or to wait for its termination.

Comment: @Ingo if this is the case, So Is there any other thing I can do, in any other language, It's very important to me.

Comment: @Ingo you can also read its `stdout` and `stderr`, and write to its `stdin` if needed. So, basically @Usama, have your process output its progress value every iteration and read the last value it outputs, store it, then resume it via a flag when executing the process again. Quite simple.

Comment: If `stdout` is used for other purposes, open up a fifo, or simply write to a file which your Java application can then read. Like a `.continue` file with the last progress inside of it. Many ways to get the progress. You won't get access to the heap, but try other IPC strategies. http://research.engineering.wustl.edu/~beardj/CtoJava.html

Comment: Also, if you're looking to see whether it's done or not, you can call `exitValue()` and catch a `IllegalThreadStateException` if it's not terminated yet, or `waitFor` to block until it stops on its own.

Comment: Thanks @soulseekah, but I can do same with processBuilder, I can read the output of the program, i can give input to the program, But Now I am stuck with the problem, That what if, the program is inpendent, the program halts at perticular place, then I wants to store it's content then resume it later.But regardless of this, I really appreciate your response. Thanks man.

Comment: I didn't tell you to ditch `ProcessBuilder`, it's absolutely fine! Read my previous responses, they contain all the necessary things for you to do what you want (given that you started the process from the same code).

Comment: Like I said, use a `.continue` file if you didn't start the process, then read it from your Java code to see where the process left off.